# Swift: Change UIAlertAction title on click

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

How do I reference `self` from within a UIAlertAction?

```
refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        // self.title = String("HELLO")
        print("Handle Ok logic here")
    }))
```

I want the title of the UIAlertAction to change when it is clicked on (as well as other things). How do I reference myself in the command for what to do when clicked on?

How do I make it where clicking on a UIAlertAction doesn't close the alert action

Comment: You can't prevent the `UIAlertController` from dismissing when a button is tapped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a `UIAlertAction` object from its own handler, just use the provided `action` parameter passed to the action handler block.

However, you cannot change the title of an action after it has been created since the `title` parameter is readonly.

Also, however, there is little reason to even change the title anyway, as alerts are always dismissed upon tapping any alert action's button.

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertController's title  property is read only. you can't assign anything. however, you can handle that to use this code.

```
var propTitle:String = "BYE" // it's property of class

func method(){
    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: propTitle, style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        self.propTitle = "HELLO"
    }))
}
```